# Associating clients with users

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I'm attempting to build an ASP.NET Core API with authentication/authorization handled by IdentityServer4. IdentityServer4 is being backed by both Identity and Entity Framework Core. My goal is a fairly standard and familiar set up, where users can login into a API developer portal where they can add "applications" (clients) and have a client id and client secret generated that they can then use to access the API, similar to how Facebook, Google, etc. handle API access.

My mental block is coming with the way IdentityServer handles Entity Framework integration. Their entities are attached to two different contexts, `ConfigurationDbContext` and `PersistedGrantDbContext`. I'm at a loss for a good way to associate one or more `Client` entities from IdentityServer4.EntityFramework with one or more `ApplicationUser` entities from my Identity context.

This seems like it would be a fairly common usage scenario, but the documentation is strangely silent on it. I've also been unable to find anything online after various and sundry searches. I'm hoping someone else has needed this same setup and can give me some advice on how to proceed.

Comment: Did you ever found the right solution to this problem? I am trying to do the exact same thing.

Comment: I know this is an old question. I am also trying to get this type of user to client relationship. If you already solve this problem, I appreciate if you can give some guidance to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

There is no association between users and clients. IdentityServer authenticates users regardless of which client they are trying to access.

If you want to implement something like "which user is allowed to use which client" semantics, that is beyond authentication. This is typically implemented in the application itself since this is application specific logic.

https://leastprivilege.com/2017/07/10/authorization-is-hard-slides-and-video-from-ndc-oslo-2017/

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm asking. I know there's no association between users and clients. That's sort of the point. Authorizing the API is going to be handled via the client credentials. I need to provide a way for users to manage a set of clients they will create to work with the API. Think of Facebook's API. You login to their developer portal and create one or more "applications". The applications are in fact just clients in IdentityServer parlance. They have an id and a secret and give you access to certain Facebook API scopes. That is what I'm looking to create.

Comment: OK - you want to build some sort of self-service management portal. That's fine - nothing in IdentityServer itself will help you with that though.

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult, but I wasn't expecting IdentityServer to handle that for me. The point of the question is that I'm trying to figure out the best way to create some sort of relationship between my Identity user and `Client` from IdentityServer. Since, the contexts are separate, I'm not sure how to do that, and was hoping for a little guidance or perhaps a better idea than what my current thinking process is.

Comment: This is an old question but I think what you are looking for is AllowedScopes.